# Is the expression "we do not rely on 'bar elahin'" a reference to Christianity?

Tags: tefilla, avodah-zarah, torah-service, christianity, zohar

The prayer Brich Shmeh from the Zohar Vayakhel 206a, which is recited during the Torah service, contains the statement ולא על בר אלהין סמיכנא. All the translations I've seen render "bar elahin" as "angel" following Daniel 3:25, but since it literally means "a son of God" I can't help but suspect that it is a reference to Christianity. Is that what's going on here, and if so, why do the translations always leave it as "angel"?

Comment: Do you really think a Jewish person believes that Jesus was the son of G-d and would call him that in prayer.

Comment: No, I interpreted it as if it were polemical, not as affirming something about Christianity.

Comment: There is a footnote on one of the Rav Soloveitchik publications (I believe it's a _machzor Rosh Hashana_) that says he omitted that phrase due to its affirming something about Christianity.

Comment: the wiki page mentions (unsourced) ולכן ב‏‏נוסח של יהדות גרמניה לא הופיעה תפילה זו

Comment: @shulem, WAF, I don't understand how saying "I don't rely on a son of God" affirms that a son of God exists. (This question is, I guess, on Rabbi Soloveitchik rather than on either of you.)

Comment: @WAF, my guess would be that he was afraid others might think it affirms something about Christianity. But that's just a guess, as I said.

Comment: But in support of @Aaron, I could see it as being a disparaging comment meaning, "we don't need some 'son of G-d', as if such a thing could even exist!"

Comment: @msh210 It wouldn't be the craziest thing done by a Jew to avoid giving "recognition" and "legitimacy" to something else.

Answer (score 3):

While I have seen online claims that it refers to Christianity (such as [here](http://musaf-shabbat.com/2012/07/13/%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%95%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D-4/)) the connection to it as a posuk from Daniel and a similar connection to tehillim, and even the linguistic statement that "bar" means "outside of" or "except for" (as spoken of [here](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9A_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%94)) are as compelling, as is the historical fact that the idea of a leader (religious or secular) being the "son of god" [predates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_of_god) Christianity's godhead [including](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_the_Great#cite_note-PA2-11) Alexander the Great.

Comment: Good point, so why the need to translate as "angel"?

Comment: "need"? I don't think it is about need, but about the common practice. Daniel 3:25 was written 550 or so years before Jesus' time and used the Aramaic phrase to refer to an angel (from melachim 2, 19:35) so this translation simply predates otehr possible references.

Comment: Yes, but the Zohar was written well into the Roman era, giving it a different historical context.

Comment: If you accept that it was written in the mid second century it would have been more likely a rejection of Roman divinity claims (cf Peppard's 2011 work) than still nascent Christian claims.

Comment: That makes sense, but does that mean a better translation is "son of (a) god"?

Comment: Well, better is a tough term. I would still prefer the translation that invokes sefer Daniel which would be "angel" becauser that understanding is 500+ years older. As to the "bettter" status if one includes (a), only Neil Armstrong knows for sure ;)

Comment: Or we can just agree it was written in Europe in the 12-13th century where Christianity was spread from country to country.

Comment: Two major sefarim have been written regarding the Zohar and many other comments - often in the form of teshuvoth - were put forth following its publication in the 13th Century. These two works were: Mitpahath Sefarim by Rav Ya`aqov Ben Tzvi Emden (HaYa`abess) z"l and Milhamoth HaShem by Rav Yihyah Ben Shelomo Qafih z"l. Both emphatically and clearly display the Zohar's contradiction to earlier sources and internal inconsistencies. The conclusion these scholars and many others was that Zohar was NOT from Rashb"i and it was all or mostly sheqer.

Comment: While Rav Yihyah of Yemen was certainly not a qabbalist, Rav Emden was, as well as the talmidh of the Ramban, Rav Yisshaq of Acco who testifies that he went to the widow of Mosheh De Leon (the Zohar's author) and was told by her that her husband had fabricated the work. The Hatham Sofer (also a qabbalist) writes in favor of Rav Emden's work - referring to him as "the Navi" - and affirms his feeling that it was mostly a forgery, and possibly a complete forgery. So what is the point? The Zohar was NEVER original to the Torah Service and CANNOT be traced back to Hazal like other literature.

Comment: Regarding the phrase bar alahin or ben elohim, they are used throughout the Tanakh and there have NOTHING to do with Christianity nor Christian ideas/theology. To project such a meaning is incorrect and anachronistic. Christians/Messianics tend to be narcissistic in this way since every time it says "yeshuah" in the Siddur/Mahzor, they think it somehow refers to Jesus (YSh"W). The same holds true for the phrase ben adam, meaning "person" or "human." This is also used in the Tanakh many times and has absolutely no reference to Christianity at all.

Answer (score 1):

> The prayer *Brich Shmeh* from the [Zohar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zohar) [**Vayakhel**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vayakhel) 206a, which is recited during the **Torah** service contains the statement ולא על בר אלהין סמיכנא.
>
> Is the expression “we do not rely on *bar elahin*” a reference to Christianity?

**No.** It is a reference to the ancient Jewish tradition of [Moses ascending to Heaven<sup>**1**</sup> to take the **Torah** down to earth, from the Angels](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103461) (because that's what **Vayakhel** is about), which are called *sons of God* in several scriptural passages (such as Job [1:6](http://www.sefaria.org/Job.1.6), [2:1](http://www.sefaria.org/Job.2.1), [38:7](http://www.sefaria.org/Job.38.7); see also the *Jewish Encyclopedia* article on [*angelology*](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/1521)), so that men would not henceforth depend upon the ruling of the heavenly court in matters of Law (see [*not in Heaven*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_in_Heaven)), but rather on the earthly [*beth din*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_din).

<sup>**1**</sup> <sub>*The ancients, whether Jewish or pagan, saw mountains (Sinai, Olympus, Atlas, etc.) as stairways to heaven*.</sub>

---

> Why do the translations always leave it as *angel* ?

Because, in [Judaism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angels_in_Judaism#Angelic_hierarchy) (just as in [Christianity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_angelology), for that matter), there are many types or groups or classes of angels ([cherubim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherub), [seraphim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seraph), [ophanim or galgalim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ophanim), etc.), and the *bene elohim* form only a small part of a much larger picture (once again, please consult the aforementioned *Jewish Encyclopedia* [article](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/1521)); in other words, such a translation would probably have been considered too technical or obscure, whereas *angel(s)*, on the other hand, is (for most people, at least) much simpler, clearer, and more straightforward. (Hope this helps).

Comment: You say that wording refers to the concept that men would "not henceforth depend on the ruling of the heavenly court...but rather on the earthly beth din."

But if that's the reference, it seems to contradict what the prayer says: that we do not depend on bar elahin, nor on mortal man, but rather on the God of heaven. Shouldn't it say something like "we do not rely on bar elahin, but on the interpretations of our sages"?

Comment: @Cislunar: (1). Though given *through* man (Moses) *to* men (Israel) and meant to be applied *by* men (beth din) *to* men (the parties involved), the Torah is nevertheless of divine origin, hence *but rather on the God of Heaven*. (2). Nevertheless, despite of its aforementioned unearthly origin, men are given by God the power to apply it directly, rather then through angelic mediation, hence *not on the sons of God*. (3). The judges parse their decisions based on and according to its eternal teachings, rather than their own private and personal whims, hence *not on mortal man*.