# Do Angels (Still) Keep the Torah?

Tags: malach-angel, kabbalat-hatorah, literalism, heaven, observance

Both the pious pre-Talmudic [Book of Jubilees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Jubilees)<sup>**1**</sup> and the [Talmudic Gemara](http://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.88b)<sup>**2**</sup> agree that Angels kept the Torah in Heaven long before it was finally revealed through Moses to the people of Israel.<sup>**3**</sup> My question would be whether traditional Judaism believes that this observance is still going on today. (The concept of [not in Heaven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_in_Heaven) seems unrelated, but I am not sure).

---

<sup>**1**</sup> From the **[Jewish Encyclopedia](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/8944)** article on the [Book of Jubilees](http://www.sefaria.org/Book_of_Jubilees):

**Note to a footnote:** In the above-linked text of *Jubilees*, from the beautiful *Sefaria* site, the verse numbering differs from the one provided below by the *Jewish Encyclopedia*; nevertheless, all one has to do is scroll a few verses below the ones referenced to obtain the intended passage.

> As a sign of its [ Israel's ] union with God, both **the Sabbath and circumcision** have been given to it, privileges which **it shares with the angels** (ch. ii. 18-21, xv. 26-27).
>
> [T]he Hasidæan author represents **circumcision as ordained in heaven** from the beginning of Creation (ch. xv. 25-27).
>
> **The Sabbath** that comes at the close of the twenty-two generations (ch. ii. 23) **was also ordained in heaven**, and was, therefore, given to no other nation but Israel, to celebrate as **it is celebrated by the angels in heaven** (ch. ii. 30-31; comp. [Sanh. 58b](http://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.58b)).
>
> It [ the *Feast of Weeks* ] was **celebrated in heaven** from the days of Creation until God ordained it to Noah.

---

<sup>**2**</sup> A small passage from the much larger context of *[Shabbat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shabbat_(Talmud)) 88b-89a*:

> [ The angels ] said before Him: [ The Torah is a ] hidden treasure that was concealed by you **974 generations** before the creation of the world, [ and ] you seek to give it to flesh and blood?

A scholarly footnote, paraphrasing [Rashi's commentary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi#Commentary_on_the_Talmud), adds the following:

> As it is stated: “The word which He **commanded** to a **thousand generations**” (Psalms 105:8). Since the Torah, the word of God, was given to the **twenty-sixth generation** after Adam, the first man, the remaining **974 generations** must have preceded the creation of the world.

Another plausible explanation for the presence of the mysterious number 974 would be Deuteronomy 7:9, ultimately amounting to the same conclusion.

---

<sup>**3**</sup> From **[Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2836562)** :

> A question is asked: which is greater? *Eino metzuvah ve’oseh* — One who is not commanded and who observes Torah on his own volition or *metzuvah ve’oseh* — one who is commanded and fulfills what he has been commanded?
>
> While at first thought one may reason that the former is greater, the Gemara ([Kiddushin 31a](http://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.31a)) says “one who performs a precept having been commanded to do so, is greater than one who performs a precept without having been commanded to do so.”
>
> **Though Hashem had not specifically given the Torah to the angels they were content since they held that observing Torah voluntarily is more commendable and receives greater reward.** However, when they saw that Moshe had come up because Hashem was going to give him Torah (though the Jews **too** observed Torah voluntarily for many years) so that they would be a *metzuvah ve’oseh* — one who is commanded and performs — they suddenly realized that they were in error all these years, and in reality one who is commanded and performs is greater.

In the comments below, a user has suggested the possibility that I might have misrepresented or misunderstood the Rabbi's words, and proposed that I get in touch with him, so as to clarify any possible misapprehensions, which I eventually obliged. Emailing him, I asked:

> Is it only a mere academic or intellectual pursuit for them, or do they actually perform (some of) its Commandments ?

To which he rather promptly [replied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoqIa.png):

> This is based on what is related in tractate Shabbat. Th[at] there was opposition from Angels to Moshes taking the Torah down to earth

which sentence is as clear as it is also cryptic. (Feels weird emailing him a second time to ask for *yet further* clarifications, though; I don't want to seem too pushy). Just thought it commonsense to mention it here, in the spirit of total transparency.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93420/discussion-on-question-by-lucian-do-angels-still-keep-the-torah).

Comment: The main reason for asking this question was because it was meant to serve as a prelude to the question I actually wanted to ask all along, namely *why do stars not cease burning on the Sabbath*, since lighting a fire is prohibited on that particular day (Exodus 35:3), the connection between the two lying in the fact that scripture seems to employ the same expression (*hosts of heaven*) to denote either angels or stars, depending on context. Though the accepted answer is partially at odds with traditional Judaism, its last paragraph nevertheless addresses this issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem, you see, is wrong assumptions!

Your question begs the question: How can angels keep Torah if they do not exist? G-d is not a Pasha surrounded by servants that carry out the Pasha's commands. G-d has no need for assistants. Yes, tradition came up with the idea that there are angels, meaning messengers from G-d. But they should not be understood as figures outside natural law. Natural law is fixed and needs no change. If one wants to think of the existence of angels, think of the natural forces such as rain, snow, the laws of gravity, etc.

Another way to think of it is when we light the Shabbat candles before Shabbat begins. Similarly, the sun is always burning (giving off light) before and after Shabbat. A mitzvah? In a way, you could say it is keeping Shabbat (metaphorically) since it would be impossible to live without daylight. Yet it should be obvious that the stars do not keep kosher. I think they observe the Torah by obeying natural law, G-d's laws. In the beginning, G-d created or established the laws of nature to work throughout eternity. Natural law is fixed and needs no change. Thus, the stars or intelligence (as Maimonides calls it) are always observing the Torah.

Comment: Is this what traditional Judaism teaches on the topic ?

Comment: It is what Maimonides taught.

Comment: No, tradition did not "come up with" the idea that there are angels.  They are described in the Torah.  It's perfectly fine to understand them as a description of natural processes, but that's not an excuse to dismiss their attributes as depicted in the Torah and Chazal.  You need to explain how those attributes describe the natural processes.  To say "it's a metaphor" and end there is just lazy.  To say "I know it's a metaphor but I don't know what it means" would be much better and more honest, though not terribly helpful.

Comment: @TurkHill: I was suspecting you were going to say that. :-) However, whether literal persons or metaphorical personifications, the angels are still supposed to obey the Torah, are they not ?

Comment: @Heshy I can explain the metaphor. First, I do believe in angels. Just not the same kind as you do. I think of them as forces of nature. The wind, snow, rain, all these are angels.

Comment: @Heshy You ask for an example. The Bible often describes G-d in anthropomorphic terms. The Rambam felt that G-d does not have emotions, for example, G-d does not get angry when you sin. Rabbi Ishmael’s famous statement is dibra torah k’lashon b’nei adam, “the Torah speaks in the language of man.” Thus, Rabbi Ishmael rightly assumed that G-d - as Maimonides explained - is transcendental and incorporeal. And although the Torah “speaks in the language people use,” it is because people have a hard time comprehending a G-d who is one which has no body.

Comment: It follows that G-d is not really a "He" for G-d has no gender. It would be more polite, and this was said by a kabbalist, to referre to Him as "It." Our disposition naturally wants to associated G-d with a “He", a father figure. But if this assumption is removed we find the concept of G-d much more rational. For we cannot know what G-d is (His essence) nor what He is doing. At best we can know what G-d is not: G-d has no body and is one. “For your ways are not My ways,” says Hashem.

Comment: @Lucian I guess you could say the wind, rain, and snow follow the Torah (metaphorically). At best they follow G-d's verbal commands (allegorically). Nevertheless, it is certainly logical to follow G-d over the Torah because the Torah is G-d's gift to man, not angels. In any event, Angels do not have free will. They cannot make mitzvahs or good deeds.

Comment: @TurkHill: Do the stars also follow the Torah ? If so, then what would be the (metaphorical or allegorical) way in which they obey the commandment of not kindling a fire during the Sabbath ?

Comment: @Lucian: think of when we light the Shabbat candles before Shabbat begins. Similarly, the sun is always burning (giving off light) before and after Shabbat. A mitzvah? (metaphorically) since it would be impossible to live without daylight. Yet it should be obvious that the stars do not keep kosher. I think they observe the Torah by obeying natural law, G-d's laws. In the beginning, G-d created or established the laws of nature to work throughout eternity. Natural law is fixed and needs no change. Thus, the stars or intelligence (as Maimonides calls it) are always observing the Torah.

Comment: May I suggest editing that into the answer?  Because what you currently have doesn't address the question.

Comment: @Heshy good suggestion.

Comment: @TurkHill: *G-d has no need for assistants.* - Then man should never have been created either, since, after all, God could have tilled the ground all by Himself (Genesis 2:5).

Comment: @Lucian: G-d is not in need of anything. Man is in need to till the soil (Genesis 2:5). The goal of the Torah is to improve the self and society. Tilling the ground is necessary for civilization.

Comment: @TurkHill: Just as man himself is not a symbolic personification of the act of tilling, so also angels are not symbolic personifications of natural laws. The latter are probably as irrelevant to them as tilling is to us.

Comment: @Lucian: Adam, who cultivates the land, was an important element for an agricultural-based society. People were worth more when it took 10 people to continue a farm. Although this value has declined in modern society, it was as important to them as the invention of the wheel is to you.

Comment: Take a car for instance. It takes you wherever you want to go. but what I can't get is the need to believe in angels in a nonrational manner. What purpose does it serve? G-d certainly has no need for them. To suggest otherwise would be insulting to an all-knowing and all-powerful G-d. Yes, the Bible is filled with angels who perform G-d's will with human anthropomorphism, but the Bible is filled with metaphors and it always exaggerates with numbers.

Comment: For example, the Torah is in love with the number 7, although not in the same way as the pagans. The pagans saw it everywhere, from the number of planets visible to the naked eye to parts of the body. The Bible uses 7 and 3 and 10 as symbols. For example, Abraham sees three angels on the third day of circumcision. Noah sent a dove seven days after the flood. Joshua marched around Jericho for seven days. G-d created the world and rested on the seventh day. The Bible is filled with symbolism. The author never intended to read the Bible literally.

Comment: This actually adds credibility to the notion that the Bible was written by a single author because primitive people could not do so.

Comment: In any case, angels most certainly do exist and there is no personification. Rather, it is a natural force such as rain, snow, and wind. Even people can be angels. An angel is anything that carries out the will of G-d. Gravity is a force that connects the universe and is an angel. If the ancients knew about the concept of gravity, they would have called it "the angel of gravity."

Comment: Removing the wrong assumptions will solve much; for then you no longer feel the need to defend religion or even G-d. True religion is when religion is defending you.

Comment: @TurkHill: God has no *need* of us either. Nor of the Universe, for that matter.

Comment: @Lucian: I agree with what you wrote. In his Guide 1:11, for example, Rambam says that G-d is “the stable one who undergoes no manner of change…nor a change in His relation to what is other than Himself” (emphasis added). This means that G-d is the same before us and will be the same after us. Certainly, G-d does not benefit from our creation. The world was probably not created for people.

Comment: Saying that G-d needs something, or is exposed to the need for things, is not only primitive in nature but it implies that G-d needs help or relies on people to "fix" a world that G-d created; which the Bible says is "Very good." It implies that G-d is like a plumber, who needs to return on a daily bases to modify His creations because it is in a state of flux. This is insulting to G-d. It is not that G-d commands a leaf, "Fall, keep falling, keep falling, keep falling. Stop. Move an inch over there."

Comment: In short, G-d is in need of nothing. He does not want sacrifices or temples, nor does He get angry when you sin. These things are only good for humans because it improves people spiritually and society.

Comment: @TurkHill: Creation is not caused by divine need. Nevertheless, it exists. And this creation includes angels. These are personal (as opposed to impersonal), and are not reduced to the various elements or forces of nature with whose oversight they have been entrusted (for the same reason man cannot be reduced to agricultural activity either, since the human experience is by far much deeper and more diverse than that).

Comment: @Lucian: I agree with what you wrote regarding creation but as you might know, I am convinced that angels are mere forces of nature. Natural elements. You will admit that it is foolish to believe in unicorns or some other 'unseen' force’, so too it is foolish to believe in angelic beings in which you cannot prove. Simply put, angels and demons do not exist. They are primitive notions held by the ancients. Today people are more educated. Natural law is fixed and needs to change.

Comment: To say G-d is in need of angels is an affront to G-d’s unity and oneness. It implies that as Creator, G-d needs assistants but in practice, G-d needs no helpers. I challenge you to prove an angel who can act as concrete evidence. Please show me a picture of an angel with wings. I'll show you my snow photo. Good luck.

Comment: @TurkHill: *it is foolish to believe in unicorns or some other ‘unseen force’* - Such as God, you mean ? :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99744/discussion-between-turk-hill-and-lucian).

Comment: @user18041 I do not include God as foolishly believing in 'unseen forces,' because at least we see the effects of God. True, we can't see God, but we can see the effects of God. For example, all of creation could come from none other but God. We can be sure that there is a God. But all other unseen forces, such as angels and demons do not display evidence of themselves and have no existence. Where are they? No one knows. No one has seen them. But you could look all around you for God. The evidence is everywhere and everything. Everything in all of creation is proof of the existence of God.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your *paraphrased* question, "Does traditional Judaism believe that Angels still *keep* the Torah today?", is yes. But their keeping is not like our keeping.

The key to understanding this is to realize that angels do not *keep* the Torah in the same way as human beings. In fact, this was the original proof which was given by Moshe Rabbeinu when the angels made their original objection to G-d about His giving the Torah to these lowly creatures of flesh and blood. The angels made their objection to G-d and G-d told Moshe Rabbeinu to answer them.

Angels are in the general category of *Sichle'im* (Intelligences without material, corporeal existence). In that state of being their perception is far greater than that of humans. And so, from the perspective that the Torah is wisdom, a thing to be studied, learned and comprehended intellectually, angels are far more suited to have the Torah than human beings.

But as Moshe pointed out as recounted in [Shabbat 88b-89a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.88b.7-8?lang=bi), the ultimate purpose of the Torah is to engage with physical, material existence. This is something outside the domain  of angelic existence generally. Angels only connect to Torah in terms of study, not in terms of fulfillment of the commandments materially. And the general rule is that the fulfillment through physical, material action is the main purpose of the Torah (המעשה הוא העיקר) like is found in [Avot 1:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1.17?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

> שִׁמְעוֹן בְּנוֹ אוֹמֵר, כָּל יָמַי גָּדַלְתִּי בֵין הַחֲכָמִים, וְלֹא מָצָאתִי לַגּוּף טוֹב אֶלָּא שְׁתִיקָה. **וְלֹא הַמִּדְרָשׁ הוּא הָעִקָּר, אֶלָּא הַמַּעֲשֶׂה**. וְכָל הַמַּרְבֶּה דְבָרִים, מֵבִיא חֵטְא:

And this is why the angels were not *commanded* to keep the Torah, like the congregation of Israel is. They study Torah and continue to do so, but cannot fulfill its commandments. From the beginning of their creation, they have not been suited for it.

This same principle is also one of the understandings about the offering of Nadav and Avihu. Even though it was *accepted*, it was not commanded. In kabbalistic language and the teachings of Chassidut, this is the concept of *Ratzu v'Shuv*, running toward G-d (to cleave to G-d) and returning (meaning connecting the result and effect of that cleaving to physical, material existence). As a consequence of their only fulfilling the Ratzu aspect, they were forfeit their lives (a soul dressed in a physical body). They were like angels. This is in keeping with what is taught in connection with the beginning of parshat Shemini 10:1-3 (see also Rashi to 10:3).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99570/discussion-on-answer-by-yaacov-deane-do-angels-still-keep-the-torah).